# DNS functions are not found

Tags: c++, c, dns, compilation, linker

I am trying to build TerraGear from the FlightGear project. I got no errors while compiling but while linking I'm getting undefined reference to multiple functions all starting with `dns_` and none of them is present in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdns.so.1100`. In which library are these defined ? Because, I googled for `dns_init` (that's one of these functions) and found no documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I should do more research before asking here ;) : these functions come from libudns, and I just forgot to link it ! :@